# How to add 0x00 at the end of a buffer

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code as:

```
char* buffer = new char[12];
memcpy(newbuffer, bytes, 10); //bytes is const void *
```

Now I want the last 2 bytes which I have not used should be appended with `0000`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy as this:

```
buffer[10]=buffer[11]=0;
```

If it was a longer range you could have used `memset` or `std::fill`.

Answer (score 2):

Use memset.

```
memset(buffer + 10, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the whole buffer before calling `memcpy` and its done for you:

```
char* buffer = new char[12];
memset(buffer, 0, 12);
memcpy(buffer, bytes, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign them directly:

```
buffer[10] = 0;
buffer[11] = 0;
```

Or put it in a loop if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Just set them to 0.

```
buffer[10] = buffer[11] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

errr..

```
buffer[10] = 0;
buffer[11] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do that for more than only two elements:

```
memset( & buffer[10], 0, 2 );
```

More generic:

```
// sets the next n elements of your array of type T
// pointed by pointer to 0.
memset( pointer, 0, n*sizeof(T) );
```

---

For just two elements the simple solution already suggested by many will probably be clearer and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C++, you should eschew manual memory management and use the Standard Library facilities that are available to you, like `std::vector`.  It is near impossible to correctly manage memory manually in C++ and it is completely necessary in all but a select few cases (like in low-level library code).

Given:

```
const char* bytes; 
std::size_t n_bytes = 10;
```

Any of the following will work:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(bytes, bytes + n_bytes);
buffer.push_back(0); // null-terminate the buffer
```

or:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(n_bytes + 1);
std::copy(bytes, bytes + n_bytes, buffer.begin());
```

or:

```
std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.reserve(n_bytes + 1);
std::copy(bytes, bytes + n_bytes, std::back_inserter(buffer));
buffer.push_back(0);
```

Which performs best depends on how `std::vector` is implemented by your compiler.  In practice, unless you are creating and destroying buffers at a relatively high frequency, you won't notice a sizable performanace difference.  The first of the three solutions presented here is the cleanest and easiest to understand at first glance.

By using `std::vector`, you don't need to worry about freeing the memory yourself and you don't need to worry about correctly destroying the dynamically allocated object when an exception causes a function to return early.  In addition, a good implementation of the Standard Library containers (like the one provided with Visual C++) provides runtime checks in debug builds that help you to find common bugs like off-by-one errors or iterator invalidation errors.

Comment: +1:  Also, since he is stating the size of the array at compile time, he could use `std::array`/`boost::array`/`std::tr1::array` in pretty much the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to fill the buffer with zeros first,  using `memset` or `std::fill`, before writing into it.